# Design and development of a training oriented CMS

Tags: .net, content-management-system

I've been commissioned to implement an application for the design (layout and content) of computer based training courses, the delivery of these courses to learners, and the conducting of exams on these courses.  Administrators must have the ability to define their own workflow and content for courses, and content is text, images, audio, and video.  The admin must also have a design surface for both workflow and content.

One big requirement is that this is a desktop/lan application, not web, otherwise I would look at a CMS like Umbraco for this.

I'm asking for recommendations for tools (open source or free) and practices and patterns I should be looking at to facilitate the development of such a system.

Comment: I fail to see how this question if off topic! I am asking other SO users to give me recommendations on resources, practices and patterns  , and tools, that could help me design and build a training oriented CMS application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Microsoft Learning Content Development System](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/training/lcds.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Erno, that looks interesting, but probably not 'open' enough for my needs, w.r.t. customization etc.  I'm developing for the provider of computer training systems to several large mining houses here in SA, and he has a rigid set of requirements from his dealings with the mines.

Comment: yes, my thoughts exactly.  UI design is a challenge for me while I spend most of my brain-juice on writing code. I always get great inspiration from existing apps.